# Discrete Mathematics Help

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Stuck on this question. Any solutions with explanations would be appreciated.

Let the subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ be given by
$A = \{(m, n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} : m + 2n \leq 5\}$.
Find a surjection $h: A \to D$, where the set $D = \{ \text{true}, \text{false}, \text{unknown} \}$.

Not entirely sure what is contained in set $A$, and how $\text{unknown}$ has a matching element in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You look confused, but it is actually a very simple question. You can take

$h(1,1) = true$

$h(2,1) = false$

$h(3,1) = unknown$

if $(m,n) \in A \setminus \{(1,1); (2,1); (3,1)\}$, then $h(m,n) = true$

I think it would be clearer with $D=\{1,2,3\}$, it is basically the same question, but less confusing. I think (just assuming) you got mixed up by the "unknown". Here, it has no meaning, it is just an element of a set. You do not want the caracteristic function of $A$ (which is fully known).

By the way, $A$ is finite, you can just list its elements if you want to know what is in it.

Comment: Can you explain why they're true, false and unknown please? Surely h(2,1) is true a

Comment: Can you explain why they're true, false and unknown please? Surely h(2,1) is true as it follows the rule. Also, how is this surjective?

Comment: @SasanFouladi-Pour Don't take the meaning of the words "false, true, unknown" literally: $\;D\;$ is only a set with three elements. Call them Joe, Moe, Larry if you want.